# Pin TabLayout to top while Toolbar below scrolls into it using AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I have a TabLayout that I want **always** pinned to the top, and a Toolbar below that, that when the view is scrolled, scrolls up into the TabLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/music_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_chooser_title"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can see here that I've set the Toolbar

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

and not set any scrolling flags for the TabLayout above, since I want it to remain pinned.   However, using these settings, the AppBarLayout doesn't scroll at all.  If I add a scroll flag to the TabLayout, then they both scroll, and the TabLayout doesn't remain fixed.  Is there a way to have the TabLayout remain fixed, while the Toolbar below scrolls up "off screen?"

Pictures can be provided if needed

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Android Design Support Library blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> One note: all views using the scroll flag must be declared before views that do not use the flag. This ensures that all views exit from the top, leaving the fixed elements behind.

So what you want is not possible with `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: hi, can you please tell how to achieve the Foursquare app scroll behaviour, as shown here: https://youtu.be/enWVNP3Gifg.